# SQL Server - BCP utility is not exporting multiple files

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm trying to export some data to XML files on a specific location, from SQL, using BCP utility. The information within my stored procedure that is generating the `XML` are selected through a view which returns the following information:

```
          GUID                          IDHeader    IDLines
-------------------------------------------------------------
A5AF1E8B-C743-4B26-979E-9B83B0037253    GEA-00008   GEA-00008
A5AF1E8B-C743-4B26-979E-9B83B0037253    GEA-00008   GEA-00008
AA4919C5-8050-4DD3-A463-F04BC0AE3F72    GEA-00011   GEA-00011
AA4919C5-8050-4DD3-A463-F04BC0AE3F72    GEA-00011   GEA-00011
5F4E196C-A360-48B7-8127-3364C7268706    GEA-00012   GEA-00012
5F4E196C-A360-48B7-8127-3364C7268706    GEA-00012   GEA-00012
F0CD1949-F8E0-4A74-B273-E9F285B844DB    GEA-00013   GEA-00013
F0CD1949-F8E0-4A74-B273-E9F285B844DB    GEA-00013   GEA-00013
```

Based on the information above, I should have 4 `XML` files generated, but somehow only 1 file is generated and I do not understand why.

Part of my code looks like this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @XMLFinal varchar(MAX) = '';
    DECLARE @nr nvarchar(100);
    DECLARE @XML varchar(MAX);


    DECLARE Records CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT
               GUID
        FROM MyView;

    OPEN Records;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Records
    INTO @nr;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @XML = '';
        SET @XML = (SELECT TOP 1
                           IDHeader,
                           IDLines
                    FROM MyView
                    WHERE GUID = @nr
                   FOR XML PATH(''));


        FETCH NEXT FROM Records
        INTO @nr;

        SET @XMLFinal = @XMLFinal + @XML;
    END;

    CLOSE Records;
    DEALLOCATE Records;


    IF @XMLFinal IS NOT NULL
   AND NOT @XMLFinal LIKE '%ORD%'
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO ExportOrder (XML,
                                 Sent)
        SELECT @XMLFinal,
               '0';

        DECLARE @XMLExport varchar(MAX);
        DECLARE @Name varchar(MAX);
        DECLARE @ID nvarchar(MAX);

        SET @ID = (SELECT TOP 1 IDHeader FROM MyView WHERE GUID = @nr);

        SET @Name = 'Order-' + @ID + '_' + FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss') + '.xml';

        SET @XMLExport = @XML;


        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##x') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE ##x;

        SELECT @XMLExport AS x
        INTO ##x;

        DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(4000);
        DECLARE @pathAndFileName nvarchar(MAX);
        DECLARE @result int;
        SET @pathAndFileName = N'C:\MyFolder\' + @Name;
        SET @cmd = N'C:\Binn\bcp.exe "SELECT  * from ##x" queryout "' + @pathAndFileName + N'" -c -T -t; ';
        EXEC @result = xp_cmdshell @cmd;
    END;
END;
```

What am I doing wrong here? What should I do to generate all 4 files? Thanks

Comment: There seems to only be 1 `EXEC`, but you are expecting to run for multiple files? If you are creating/reading multiple files I would expect multiple calls.

Comment: Your code does not have any loop and there is only one call of bcp, so how can you expect more than 1 file?

Comment: There is a cursor which select distinct GUID from that view and pass the value to @Nr.

Comment: Not in the code you've supplied there isn't @srkkk . How do you propose we debug code that we can't see? Could you post the **full** code please?

Comment: @Larnu - done it.

Comment: I'm getting errors in your code. Line 18 only contains the text `...............`, and you're missing 2 `END`s at the end. That is not your **FULL** code. If it isn't your full code, how can we trust that the part which you say isn't work is in the snippet you've given us?

Comment: Sorry, did not think it was relevant.

Comment: OK, so why are you expecting 4 files again? `EXEC @result = xp_cmdshell @cmd;` isn't inside a `WHILE`, or any kind of looping structure; it's only called once. The comments from myself and @sepupic still stands.

Comment: You were right. I moved fetching the next value after `EXEC @result =...`. Thanks